# .htaccess loading files with .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my .Htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/freshadmin/
RewriteRule ^styles/(.+)?$ templates/styles/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.+)?$ templates/scripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^icons/(.+)?$ templates/icons/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)?$ templates/images/$1 [L]

# Removed Redirect Loop #1518
#RewriteRule ^ajax/(.+)?$ ajax/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to load pages with php extensions. I removed last line

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and load the page even with .php but it says 404 Not Found
I am entering my page like this. www.mysite.com/admin/index.php
but 404 error occurs.

Comment: Check your `RewriteBase /news/freshadmin/`, maybe your path is wrong?